# How to create a subtraction in the inventory when a order is made? [Django] [Python] [E-commerce website]

Tags: python, django, inventory

I’m a python/django begginer. I decided to build a e-commerce website using django for an academic project. I’ve been able to develop enough of the project and build understanding of the subject, but right now I’m having issues finding a way to subtracts the number of items listed in the inventory whenever a order is made.

That’s the code for the models, evey product has it's own stock quantity call inventory:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    description = models.TextField(default='', null=True, blank=True)
    digital = models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    inventory = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def has_inventory(self):
        return self.inventory > 0
```

This is the code I made to subtract base on quantity of the item ordered, but I can’t make it work, it won’t subtract the number of items from the inventory on the product stock.

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.product) + " x " + str(self.quantity)

    def inventory(self):
        product.inventory = self.inventory
        product.inventory -= int(self.quantity)
        return inventory
```

What could I do to make it work?

Comment: Well, one big problem is in your `OrderItem.inventory` function, because `self.inventory` is that function.  It's not a value.  You wouldn't track the inventory in the data models like this, you'd track it in your HTML response.  These model classes are just holding data.  They usually do not take any actions.

Answer (score 0):

All logic/action should be written under `views.py` file. You could create a function where it takes in a request, and when it does, it takes in all the value inputted through a form, and you could use `filter` to filter out the products you want to subtract its inventory and `update` query by Django to update the inventory.

It should look something like this inside your views function:

```py
Product.objects.filter(name = name, description = description, digital = digital).update(Inventory = F('Inventory')-inventory)
```

Here is Django's documentation on queries: [Django's Making Queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/)

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a few problems with the snippet above.

First, the `OrderItem.inventory` is not referring the right value, it should be like the snippet below.

```
    def inventory(self):
        // remember the current stock is stored on Product.inventory
        return self.product.inventory - self.quantity
```

Second, The method name should be `remaining_stock` not `inventory` to prevent misunderstanding.

```
    def remaining_stock(self):
        return self.product.inventory - self.quantity
```

Also, don't forget if you want to store `inventory` of the product please call the `save` method after successfully inserting the `OrderItem.`